# Windows Powershell equivalent to this Linux command that calculates a number to 10000 decimal places?

Tags: powershell, math, decimal, precision

I have seen this fun little command going around on social media, which outputs pi to 10000 decimal places. I'm wondering what is the Windows Powershell equivalent to this?

```
echo "scale=10000; 4*a(1)" | bc -l
```

I know I can use the [Powershell Math library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.atan?view=net-5.0#System_Math_Atan_System_Double_) to do the basic math formula, but how to set the number of decimal places to 10000?

```
PS C:\Users\Me> [Math]::Atan(1)*4
3.14159265358979
```

Comment: There is no native functionality in .NET for this. .NET has no arbitrary-precision numerics library built in, so neither does PowerShell. For integer calculations there is `BigInteger`, but that can't be used for floating-point calculations like this. You can look for arbitrary precision numerics libraries for .NET and use those in PowerShell, or just install and invoke `bc` (it's a separate executable, not a built-in command).

Comment: There is a [DECIMAL type in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=net-5.0), but that's only good for 96 bits of precision, and it doesn't appear that you can use the [Math]:: trig functions on it.

Comment: Of course, as long as you don't mind cheating, a native equivalent could be `(Invoke-WebRequest https://www.pi2e.ch/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/pi_dec_1m.txt).Content | Select -First 10001`. You can request even more digits and it's much faster than `bc`. :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`[Math]` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math?view=net-5.0) only works with `double` so obviously you can't get more than 53 bits of precision. A few of its methods also support [decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=net-5.0) so you'll get a little bit more digits but obviously no way near 10000 digits. There's no [arbitrary precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) floating point type in .NET so you're completely on your own to calculate the digits if you don't want to retrieve them from some storage space

There's [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-5.0) (PowerShell type accelerator name: `[bigint]`) though, which helps a lot since you won't need to do arbitrary precision math yourself. For example to calculate 10000 digits of *π* you can calculate *10000π* and does the operations in integer or [fixed point math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic)

There are [many algorithms to do that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Modern_quest_for_more_digits) such as this one: [How does this code calculate pi with high precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39802720/995714)

Fortunately [Rosetta Code has a sample snippet to calculate π](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Pi#Powershell). After the below function has been declared just call `Get-Pi 10000` to get the desired output

```powershell
Function Get-Pi ( $Digits )
    {
    $Big = [bigint[]](0..10)
 
    $ndigits = 0
    $Output = ""
 
    $q = $t = $k = $Big[1]
    $r =           $Big[0]
    $l = $n =      $Big[3]
    # Calculate first digit
    $nr = ( $Big[2] * $q + $r ) * $l
    $nn = ( $q * ( $Big[7] * $k + $Big[2] ) + $r * $l ) / ( $t * $l )
    $q *= $k
    $t *= $l
    $l += $Big[2]
    $k = $k + $Big[1]
    $n = $nn
    $r = $nr
 
    $Output += [string]$n + '.'
    $ndigits++
 
    $nr = $Big[10] * ( $r - $n * $t )
    $n = ( ( $Big[10] * ( 3 * $q + $r ) ) / $t ) - 10 * $n
    $q *= $Big[10]
    $r = $nr
 
    While ( $ndigits -lt $Digits )
        {
        While ( $ndigits % 100 -ne 0 -or -not $Output )
            {
            If ( $Big[4] * $q + $r - $t -lt $n * $t )
                {
                $Output += [string]$n
                $ndigits++
                $nr = $Big[10] * ( $r - $n * $t )
                $n = ( ( $Big[10] * ( 3 * $q + $r ) ) / $t ) - 10 * $n
                $q *= $Big[10]
                $r = $nr
                }
            Else
                {
                $nr = ( $Big[2] * $q + $r ) * $l
                $nn = ( $q * ( $Big[7] * $k + $Big[2] ) + $r * $l ) / ( $t * $l )
                $q *= $k
                $t *= $l
                $l += $Big[2]
                $k = $k + $Big[1]
                $n = $nn
                $r = $nr
                }
            }
        $Output
        $Output = ""
        }
    }
```

Comment: Simplicity itself! This is but the first step for PowerShell on the road to full employment as a language for number crunching. :-)